# Xamarin Forms: Nesting a visual element across multiple views

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I would like to add a Floating Action Button to multiple views. I was wondering if there is a method similar to the ASP.NET `_Layout.cshtml` pages. Is there a way to house the view in a page and render the content underneath it?

I have tried adding it to the MasterDetailPage, but I am not sure if it's me doing it wrong or if it's just not supported.

I can add the view to each page, but I'd really prefer to explore this method from a maintainability point of view.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/xamarinforms-floating-action-button

Comment: Thanks for the link, this does not answer my question of being able to nest that view in a way where it is persistent across multiple views

Comment: You want the floating action button on every screen?

Comment: I want to know if it's possible, yes

Comment: It is possible. Create your own CustomPage which inherits from ContentPage. Create base layout for the CustomPage that has AbsoluteLayout/Grid as root layout, place your Floating Action Button and add another layout inside(e.g. StackLayout) which will contain whatever that page should contain (you should manipulate UI in your code-behind of CustomPage.xaml.cs).

Comment: @zpouip do you have an example of this working in a MasterDetail app? I am having trouble making the base class content render on top of the content of the page that inherits from it.

Answer (score 0):

> if it's possible ?

Of course you can implement it. No matter MasterDetailPage or Tabbed Page . Each **View** is a ContentPage. So you can create a general ContentPage (for example we call it BaseContentPage).

And define the floating button in it. Then create its subclass as each view so that you can handle the different logic in different pages .

Comment: Thanks for the response, this doesn't seem much different to adding the view to each page manually but it is cleaner. In trying this I have found one difficulty. Because I am declaring the FAB first, it seems to be sitting under the content of the views that derive from it. I'm struggling to find a way to move it over. Do you have any examples of this?

Comment: You can create a custom button.